# ARKit - Supporting ZAxis inclinations

Tags: iphone

Well, I am messing around ARKit and realized that when I pitch the device (rotate through the Z axis, changing from Potrait to Landscape and viceversa), the points move to non correctly regions.
I tried adding shouldRotate, and didRotate methods to handle it but didn't get no results.. :(
Does someone have the same problem? Knows how to fix it?
Thank you in advance guys.

```
//this should be different based on orientation.

rollingZ  = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingZ  * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
rollingX = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (rollingX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
```

I have tried to change this lines too, these seem to be the key, but I can't solve it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours testing, changing values and trying millions of demos found on the internet, I found this ARKit Source with Device Orientation. 
[Argami iPhone-AR-Toolkit which supports device Orientation](https://github.com/argami/iPhone-AR-Toolkit)

Enjoy it!